# How to change format from str to datetime in python

Tags: python, string, datetime

I have a string like this:

```
'2021-07-24'
```

I want to change this to datetime type like this:

```
2021-07-24T00:00:00.000+09:00
```

How to replace str with datetime like that format?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting string into datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/466345/converting-string-into-datetime)

Comment: You will find this helpful:- https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html

Comment: where does the UTC offset of +9 hours come from?

Comment: basically `datetime.fromisoformat('2021-07-24').replace(tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=9))).isoformat()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**You can try this:**

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta

dt_obj = datetime.fromisoformat('2021-07-24').replace(tzinfo=timezone(timedelta(hours=9))).isoformat()

print(dt_obj)
```

**Output:**
`2021-07-24T00:00:00+09:00`

Comment: Please refrain from answering common duplicates. Instead, vote to close as duplicate.